# App to help (manually) choose network provider

Tags: iphone, network, sim

I have a dual-sim iPhone 13, which I use when commuting across the Swiss-EU border. With my current Swiss phone plan, I have free data roaming within the EU.

When in Switzerland, I have `Automatic Network Selection` enabled. However, when roaming in neighbouring EU countries, I would like to *manually* choose my network provider. However, doing this by going to `Mobile Data` > `SIM` > `Mobile Data Network` and letting the iPhone search for all available providers can take up to 5 minutes.

Is there an app that can manually select the network provider when roaming, such that I don't have to switch between automatic (when at home) and manual (when roaming) network selection?